# How to avoid multiple jobs spawning scenio in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an application wherein I should query hive which would return me a set of records(hardly 50). For each record returned I have to fire a query on hive and get the relavant dataframe. This is how it would look like:

```
val employeeIds = hiveContext.sql("select id from employee")
val vertices = employeeIds.foreach(row => {

  val employeeId = row.getInt(0)

  val query = s""" select * from department where employeeId = $employeeId"""

  //.... I would have to create a hive context here ....

})
```

But if I do so there will be new contexts spawning up from the executors, any pointers to eliminate this approach would be very helpful.

**Note:
I have masked the information to post of stackoverflow. I have to fire a query based on the records of first query. I cannot join employee and department table.**

Comment: why can't you use exiting hivecontext?? or do select * from department where employeeId in <list of employees>

Comment: The amount of data generated from each select on department table is very high so I have taken an approach to pull the records employee by employee. But as you proposed `select * from department where employeeId in <list of employees>` doesn't work in my case.

Comment: why can't you use exiting hivecontext?? you are running queries sequentially.

Comment: As far as I understand, any select query you write on sqlContext executes on executor. In this case, if I use sqlContext from within `foreach` there will be more executors spawned which report to the executor and not to the driver. this would be like a tree. Driver has few executors and executors spawn few more executors.